# Choosing which for loop based on If boolean condition

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, if-statement

I have a boolean flag. Based on this flag being false or true, my application should go to the corresponding for loop. The loops are exactly the same, besides if false, I only want to loop i/j = 1-2. If true, I want to loop i/j = 1-3. Maybe there is a more efficient way then creating a flag, however, I am getting an error on the structure of second loop.

```
  Dim Ti(0 To 3) As String
  Ti(1) = "Temperature"
  Ti(2) = "Outside Temperature"
  Ti(3) = "Inside Temperature"

  Dim Tj(0 To 3) As String
  Tj(1) = "Temperature"
  Tj(2) = "Outside Temperature"
  Tj(3) = "Inside Temperature"

  Flag1 = 0
  Flag2 = 0
  TCSflag = 0

  If onlyflag = False Then
            For i = 1 To 2
                TCChannel = Me.Controls.Item("TCSDropDown" & i).Text
                If TCChannel = "Not Available" Then
                ElseIf TCChannel = "Select Temp" Then
                    TCSflag = TCSflag + 1
                    MsgBox("Please select a temp for" & " " & Ti(i), vbCritical, "Error")
                    Exit For
                Else
                    If InStr(1, TCChannel, "Type 1") Then
                        Flag1 = 1
                    End If
                    If InStr(1, TCChannel, "Type 2") Then
                        Flag2 = 1
                    End If

                    For j = 1 To 2

                        If Ti(i) <> Tj(j) Then
                            TCChannel1 = Me.Controls.Item("TCSDropDown" & j).Text
                            If TCChannel1 = "Not Available" Then
                            Else
                                If TCChannel = TCChannel1 Then
                                    MsgBox("You selected the same temp for both " & Ti(i) & " and " & Tj(j), vbCritical, "Conflicting Temp Selection!")
                                    TCSflag = TCSflag + 1
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next

                    If TCSflag >= 1 Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next

        Else onlyflag = True
            For i = 1 To 3
            TCChannel = Me.Controls.Item("TCSDropDown" & i).Text
            If TCChannel = "Not Available" Then
                ElseIf TCChannel = "Select Temp" Then
                    TCSflag = TCSflag + 1
                    MsgBox("Please select a temp for" & " " & Ti(i), vbCritical, "Error")
                Exit For
            Else
                    If InStr(1, TCChannel, "Type 1") Then
                        Flag1 = 1
                    End If
                    If InStr(1, TCChannel, "Type 2") Then
                        Flag2 = 1
                    End If

                    For j = 1 To 3

                    If Ti(i) <> Tj(j) Then
                        TCChannel1 = Me.Controls.Item("TCSDropDown" & j).Text
                        If TCChannel1 = "Not Available" Then
                        Else
                            If TCChannel = TCChannel1 Then
                                MsgBox("You selected the same temp for both " & Ti(i) & " and " & Tj(j), vbCritical, "Conflicting Temp Selection!")
                                TCSflag = TCSflag + 1
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next

                    If TCSflag >= 1 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                End If
                End If
        Next
```

Comment: The thing that I see wrong in the code as pasted is `Else onlyflag = True`; perhaps you meant for the `onlyflag = True` part to be in a comment?  I don't think it would compile as presented.  (The accepted answer is a better choice than fixing it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set up a variable for the amount of times to loop based on your true or false?

```
 Dim Ti(0 To 3) As String
  Ti(1) = "Temperature"
  Ti(2) = "Outside Temperature"
  Ti(3) = "Inside Temperature"

  Dim Tj(0 To 3) As String
  Tj(1) = "Temperature"
  Tj(2) = "Outside Temperature"
  Tj(3) = "Inside Temperature"

  Flag1 = 0
  Flag2 = 0
  TCSflag = 0
  upperLimit = 3
  If onlyflag = False Then
     upperLimit = 2
  EndIf

            For i = 1 To upperLimit
                TCChannel = Me.Controls.Item("TCSDropDown" & i).Text
                If TCChannel = "Not Available" Then
                ElseIf TCChannel = "Select Temp" Then
                    TCSflag = TCSflag + 1
                    MsgBox("Please select a temp for" & " " & Ti(i), vbCritical, "Error")
                    Exit For
                Else
                    If InStr(1, TCChannel, "Type 1") Then
                        Flag1 = 1
                    End If
                    If InStr(1, TCChannel, "Type 2") Then
                        Flag2 = 1
                    End If

                    For j = 1 To upperLimit

                        If Ti(i) <> Tj(j) Then
                            TCChannel1 = Me.Controls.Item("TCSDropDown" & j).Text
                            If TCChannel1 = "Not Available" Then
                            Else
                                If TCChannel = TCChannel1 Then
                                    MsgBox("You selected the same temp for both " & Ti(i) & " and " & Tj(j), vbCritical, "Conflicting Temp Selection!")
                                    TCSflag = TCSflag + 1
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next

                    If TCSflag >= 1 Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
```

Comment: the upperLimit works perfectly. Thank you, I figured there was a more efficient way, still learning.